# Does system restore remove Windows updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, system-restore

If I make a system restore, it removes programs that I installed recently. But will it do the same for recent updates, or are they permanent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of of course. It just restores your PC to the previous state! Including everything.

But actually it won't remove everything completely. It dumps all the old files into a *reserved folder* which you cannot access.

Comment: Almost everything. It's not the same as a physical backup and restore. Depend on it once too often and you end up with an unstable system.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs I made a system restore, and lost some updates. The Windows update does not re-install them and the date of last update became earlier than before system restore (((

Comment: It appears this answer is no longer accurate.  http://superuser.com/questions/1036777/when-did-system-restore-stop-affecting-windows-updates asks about when the change occurred.

Comment: I think still It is accurate. The question is related to Windows 7 PCs. Not Windows 8 or Win 10. These PCs have different meaning when it comes to restore and reset.

Answer (score 2):

It removes them without really removing them. The restore point is a collection of all the files, configuration and registry settings that were needed for windows to run when the setpoint was recorded.

This is known as the system state and is in fact what you back up with `Windows Backup` if you want an off-machine backup of a restore point.

When you do a system restore, it overwrites the current system state without doing any actual uninstalling of any recent updates. Windows Update can read the current system state and reapply updates that it can recognize as needing to be reapplied, though this may fail.

Where you can have issues is when there are various non-os patches that get a partial overwrite of some of the installed files when the system restore is run.

Comment: I made a system restore, and lost some updates. The Windows update does not re-install them and the date of last update became earlier than before system restore (((

Comment: Yep, you will lose stuff, drivers, patches, registry settings all get reverted to the time the restore point was created so anything installed after that date kind of gets munged. I kind of treat System Restore as being an eventually system breaking kludge. Use only when absolutely system stopping stuff occurs. And sorry to hear about Windows Update failure, it can and does happen, you may have to look up the KB instances and manually install from Microsoft Download. Noted in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Windows will remove those programs if you restore the system to a previous restore point and maybe recent updates too. I'm not a user of Windows system restore because of issues and complexities.

I have [Deep Freeze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29) on my machine through which I can easily manage the system restore. A simple restart solves most PC problems.