# When did System Restore stop affecting Windows Updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, system-restore

Recently, I allowed Windows Update to install what it said were important updates.  Immediately after the update, programs that were working fine just before the update were no longer working, crashing on startup every time.

I did a System Restore to a little while (hours) before the Windows Updates and restarted; System Restore reported that it had successfully restored to that selected restore point. However, the programs were still consistently crashing on startup.  Opening Windows Update, it said that no important updates were available, Windows was up to date, and showed the update history including those that I thought would have been rolled back, especially looking at the accepted answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/694026/does-system-restore-remove-windows-updates).  Right-clicking on anything in the update history, I can only View Details or Copy Details, but not roll back the change.  So, those important programs just don't work any more (until such time as an update for the program is available) and I've learned my lesson about installing Windows Updates.

When did this behavior change, that System Restore no longer rolls back Windows Updates?

Comment: I really do not know what happened here and why. In any case it is strange. In the future I suggest you make your own images. Then you are in control. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I

Comment: You need to tell us which updates you installed.  Windows Update creates restore points when applicable.

Comment: Yes, I can see that Windows Update created a restore point, but by the title/text it was unclear if that restore point was just before or after updates were applied, so I chose the restore point a few hours earlier, which I *knew* to be before the updates.  Restoring to that earlier point did not undo the Windows Updates.

Comment: Some Windows updates cannot be removed after installation, Restore points are labeled at the time of the restore point so it should roll back before the update was installed. Some updates do not set a restore point so you may have to pick an earlier date.